# Make gg=G work in Evil-Mode to indent whole buffer?

Tags: emacs, evil-mode

I'm trying to move from Vim to Emacs using Evil mode, but can't get `gg=G` to indent the whole buffer working.

- `gg` correctly moves the cursor to the top of the buffer
- `G` correctly moves the cursor to the bottom of the buffer
- `==` correctly indents the current line

However the combination `gg=G` just doesn't work and I can't work out how to define it myself.

I have the following function defined to indent the whole buffer:

```
(defun indent-whole-buffer ()
    "indent whole buffer and untabify it"
    (interactive)
    (delete-trailing-whitespace)
    (indent-region (point-min) (point-max) nil)
    (untabify (point-min) (point-max)))
```

However if I try to bind it to `gg=G` like this: `(define-key evil-normal-state-map "gg=G" 'indent-whole-buffer)`, then `gg` no longer works. I'm stuck. Help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without rebinding anything, the simplest thing to do is `ggVG=`, which will 1) take you to the top of the buffer, 2) enter visual line state, 3) take you to the end of the buffer, and 4) indent everything you just highlighted.  *EDIT: are you sure `gg=G` doesn't work?  It gives the expected behavior for me.*

It'll be best if you forget how Vim does key bindings and look into how Emacs does keymaps (see [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Key-Bindings.html), [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Key-Binding-Commands.html), and [here](http://ergoemacs.org/emacs/keyboard_shortcuts.html) to get started). In this specific instance, you'll want to remember that you can't have a long sequence of keys (eg, `gg=G`) as well as a shorter subset (`gg`) because you're effectively overwriting the shorter subset (ie, you can't get to `gg=G` without first entering `gg`).

So, for example, let's say you wrote a custom function to indent the entire buffer:

```
(defun indent-buffer ()
  "Apply indentation rule to the entire buffer."
  (interactive)
  (indent-region (point-min) (point-max)))
```

You could then bind it to an unbound key such as `Q` (or a sequence like `gQ`, or overwrite something else) in the normal state map as:

```
(define-key evil-normal-state-map "Q" 'indent-buffer)
```

(EDIT: d'oh, I'd forgotten that you'd written your function already; sorry for the duplication.)

Comment: I must have been doing something weird last night... as you're right, this morning it works. D'oh. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Just comment that another and maybe more natural option is to use the `:motion` `mark-whole-buffer`, default bind `C-x h`. The advantage is that you do not need to move the cursor.

So, with `= C-x h` in normal state the whole buffer is indented and the cursor position is preserved.

Of course, with something like

```
(define-key evil-normal-state-map "Q" #'mark-whole-buffer)
```

we can avoid the use of "control", now `=Q` would indent the whole buffer. Plus the new binding `Q` could be handy for many other evil operators.